# can't override syntax highlighting in sublime text 3

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I manually installed a package awhile back for ST3 that had additional syntax highlighting languages. I have since removed it, and for the files it affected selected 'Open all with current extension as..' to now be Java. However when I re-open them they still default to the old package language. If I open up the syntax highlighting menu both languages are actually highlighted. If I reselect Java it will be correct until I close and re-open any file with that extension again.

Can anyone explain how I can either force it to always stay in Java or remove the other language all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages` and navigate to the `User` folder. There should be a file in there named `OtherLanguage.sublime-settings`. Delete that file, restart Sublime, and you should be all set. If that still doesn't work, look for a `Java.sublime-settings` file in the same directory. Delete that as well, restart, and you should be back to the default behavior. Open a file with the extension, select `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as...` and select Java. This will create a new `Packages/User/Java.sublime-settings` file, so don't delete it!

Comment: I didn't see an OtherLanguage.sublime-settings file but I do believe I saw a file for the package language (Apex), maybe it was called OtherLanguage? I removed early on in trying to fix this. I deleted the Java.sublime-settings file and reset it to be the default with that extension and upon opening a new file its still defaulting to Apex. Where else could the Apex setting be hidden?

Comment: Were you using [MavensMate-Sublime](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText)? If so, you'll also want to remove `Packages/User/mavensmate.sublime-settings` if it exists. Make sure you've completely removed `Packages/MavensMate` as well.

Comment: Well I still am using MavensMate, I had installed the forceDotbundle package though, that's where the Apex syntax highlighting came from. https://github.com/joshbirk/ForceDotBundle

Comment: I got it. Apex.sublime-setttings was still there. For some reason it turned up on search but if I navigated to the folder it wasn't displaying. I deleted it and now its defaulting back to Java. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The open all with current extension as... is what I was looking for.